# Android parse many json arrays

Tags: android, json

I have a PHP script which returns 10 json arrays one after the other. I know how to parse one json array, but how do I parse more?
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(data); i use this when I get just one json array returned, but how do I split the data into 10 json arrays for further parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse it as a `JSONObject` and parse each `key` in the object as a `JSONArray`. Assuming the data is in the format:

```
{
    array_1: [],
    array_2: [],
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's not but I will make it be :)